# How to develop multiserver web applications?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm wondering how to develop multiserver web applications (ASP.NET). Any articles, books ?

Comment: do you mean splitting logic across multiple web services on multiple servers?  or just the hardware aspect of using load balancers to route requests to a pool of servers?

Comment: I mean splitting logic across multiple servers. E.g. we have the need to connect the 2nd server (and later more servers) because there is too many users at the same time, and only one server doesn't cope with that and the page is being run slow

Answer (score 2):

Here is the MSDN Article on how do just that:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815162